# Macbook Pro not waking up on click (external monitor and thunderbolt dock)

Tags: display, sleep-wake, dock, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4
System Version: macOS 10.15.4 (19E287)
Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015

I have a macbook pro plugged into an [external monitor](http://dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-ultrasharp-24-monitor-u2412m/apd/210-agss/monitors-monitor-accessories) via a thunderbolt dock (I believe [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=caldigit%20thunderbolt%20dock&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk038Eio2vn_14J_VxTEIDRGpP8wKFQ:1590006156950&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9srPBosPpAhVel3IEHU3RAnkQ_AUoAnoECA8QBA&biw=960&bih=1097#imgrc=SH9ehMUU0UMDrM)). Often, when the computer goes to sleep (image below of my settings), it often gets into a state where I can't wake it up by pressing on my mouse/keyboard. I.e., my trackpad will click (therefore, the computer is not shut down), but the computer will not respond. Neither the external monitor, nor the laptop display will respond. The only way I can get it to turn on is to either power it down and power it up, or to unplug my thunderbolt dock. Does anyone know why this is happening/how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a reset of the SMC? This might help fix any issues related to power. You can also try resetting the NVRAM if you think it has something to do with your settings. Check out the two following links to reset the SMC and NVRAM.   SMC: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295  NVRAM: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: What happens if you press the power button?  It may be in something called “Safe Sleep.”

Comment: @Allan nothing seems to happen when I hit the power (if I hold it, ofc, it will eventually power down).

Comment: Does this happen when the Mac has been sleeping fir a while or only a short time (or either)?